# Algorithm for Combinational Values

Tags: algorithm, math

I was trying to write an algorithm for given problem:

we are given a set of numbers- {n1,n2,n3,n4,n5......}
and we have to check that can we derive a number(Say X) using addition and subtraction by given numbers. X will always be less than all elements of the given set.

Eg.

Set: {2,3,4,6,9}
given number: 1, Result: Yes
9-4-4 =1

Set: {3,4,6,9}
given number: 2, Result: Yes
6-4 = 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _multiple_ is OK? so if there is 1, every number is _yes_.

Comment: @Dante Jiang : Yes you are right. and i am considering multiple as consecutive number of addition so multiple is also ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively you are looking for the [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29) generated by the numbers in your set.  The intergers form a [principal ideal domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), which means every ideal is generated by a single integer.  All you have to do is find this single integer -- say g -- and check whether X can be devided by g.  Finding g is also easy -- it's the greatest common divisor of all elements in your set, which can be found using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

You example sets can generate every integer by addition and substraction, since the can generate 1.  For example for the set {3,4,6,9} you have 1=4-3, and any integer n can be written as n times the sum of 4-3.

Comment: Just a small correction: *any integer n can be written...*, any strictly positive integer. For 0 you use `4-4` and for negatives you sum `3-4`. Also +1 to get the `math` badge. Your answer is a bit theoretical for this forum, but it's a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming, from your first example, that you can use a number multiple times.*

The *given number* must be a multiple of the GCD of your set. That is the only condition. It doesn't matter how big it is.

If you only want an Yes/No answer then it is sufficient to find the GCD. If you also want an expression for the *given number* the problem can be replaced with finding an expression for the GCD.

```
GCD = X+Y+..+Z-T-U-...-V
```